# Mime type for WKT?

Tags: well-known-text, http-headers

What is mime type for Well-known Text (WKT)? `text/wkt`?

Comment: I don't see the connection to GIS, but feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: text/plain I guess. Or did you find other candidates from https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml?

Comment: Maybe `mimeType="application/wkt"`. https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wps/operations.html#retrieve-the-wps-execute-input-values

Comment: I can find some uses of x-wkt but x- tree is not recommended.  "application" tree is meant for "information that must be processed by an application before it is viewable or usable by a user."

Comment: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046.html `The "application" media type is to be used for discrete data which do not fit in any of the other categories, and particularly for data to be processed by some type of application program.  This is information which must be processed by an application before it is viewable or usable by a user. ` So perhaps that fits WKB but certainly not WKT

Comment: `The simplest and most important subtype of "text" is "plain".  This
   indicates plain text that does not contain any formatting commands or
   directives. Plain text is intended to be displayed "as-is", that is,
   no interpretation of embedded formatting commands, font attribute
   specifications, processing instructions, interpretation directives,
   or content markup should be necessary for proper display.  The
   default media type of "text/plain; charset=us-ascii"` and `Unrecognized subtypes of "text" should be treated as subtype "plain"`

Comment: W3C [Spatial data on the Web Best Practice document](https://www.w3.org/TR/sdw-bp/#applicability-formatVbp) has WKT as `text/plain`

Comment: WKT is certainly not `intended to be displayed "as-is"`, since it needs to be parsed by an application in order to see the shapes. How can it qualify as `text/plain`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [W3C Spatial data on the Web Best Practice document](https://www.w3.org/TR/sdw-bp/#applicability-formatVbp) has WKT as text/plain

[@nmtoken](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/27874/nmtoken)